# Spring @Transactional behaviour in case of multiple update queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a method that should perform multiple updates and want to be sure that if one update fails then no updates are commited to the database, the code looks like:

```
    private void updateStatuses(List<Status> statuses, String docId) {
        statuses.forEach(status-> {
            Long nextVersionNumber = Long.parseLong(status.getRecordVersionNbr()) + 1;
            getJdbcTemplate().update(
                    UPDATE_FUNDS_TRANSFER_DOC_ID_SQL,
                    nextVersionNumber,
                    docId,
                    status.getStatusId());
        });
    }
```

I want to annotate this method with org.springframework.transaction.annotation. @Transactional, would this work for me? Should I specify some extra-parameters?

Comment: Yes and yes: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work like charms! :)

I hope you have already configured the Transaction Manager in your Spring Configuration.

If you want to specify the Propagation and Rollback then you can do it as follows:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=DAOException.class)
```